# I have currently a problem while grabbing class value generated from php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have a problem with jQuery & PHP.

When I try to target on click on class ".id_annonce" from generated php code it does not grab me the exact value I clicked but another one and it's always fix, input hidden value is 18 when it should be 19 or 20.

**Jquery code :**

```
var commander = $(this).val();
  var beta = $('body .id_annonce').val();
  window.location.href = 'panier.php?id='+ commander +'?annonce='+ beta + '';
```

**My php code :**

```php
require 'produits.php';
$pro = new produits;
$coll = $pro->getAllproduits();
foreach ($coll as $key => $value) {

    echo '<div class="card-body  my-3 border-top" >
        <img src="img/resize.jpg" class="card-img-top  " style="height:88px;width:88px;margin-left:20px;float:right;" alt="...">   
        <h3 class="card-title p-2" style="font-size:10px;font-style:none;font-weight:600;"><strong>Ajouté Le : </strong> ' . $value['date_ajout'] . '</h3>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <h6 class="card-subtitle p-2  mb-2  text-muted"><strong>Varieté : </strong>' . $value["variete"] . '</h6>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle p-2 mb-2  text-muted" style="font-style:none;"><strong>Especes :  </strong>5000 tonnes</h6></div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <h6 class="card-subtitle p-2  text-muted"><strong>Classe : </strong>' . $value["classes"] . '</h6>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle p-2  text-muted" style="font-style:none;"><strong> Quantité :  </strong>' . $value["quantite"] . '</h6></div>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle p-2 mb-2 mt-1 text-muted" style="font-style:none;float:right;font-size:24px;">    <strong>Prix : </strong> ' . $value["prix"] . 'DA/kg</h6> 
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="p-1"> <button  class="details" value="' . $value["id"] . '" style="border:none;background:none;"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x  pr-2 text-success"></i></button></div>
        <div class="p-1">
        <input type="hidden"  value="' . $value["id"] . '"  class="id_annonce">
        <button class="commander btn btn-md  btn-outline-dark " value="' . $value["id_commande"] . '"> Commander <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart  pr-2 "></i></button></div>
        <div class="p-1">  

        <button  value="' . $value["Interesser"] . '" class="interesser btn  btn-md text-dark" style="border-color:green;font-weight:600;">Interesser(' . $value["Interesser"] . ')</button></div></div></div>';

}
```

Comment: You do not have any hidden input there, which one do you mean? Also note that when rendering code (JS/HTML) with PHP it will not change again from PHP side once it is in the browser.

Comment: Hello , i just edited  <input type="hidden"  value="' . $value["id"] . '"  class="id_annonce">
when i show it on text it show me the right value but while on click it grab me the previous $value one

for example i have 2 $value , $value[0] = 18 , $ value[1] = 19 it always grab me the first one not the 2nd one i think it's because name of the class (.id_annonce)  who is same but i have no idea how i could fix it

Comment: For one your input is lacking a [name attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden#Additional_attributes). What is the desired behavior of the javascript you posted? Since you are outputting multiple inputs, which one should the javascript take?

Comment: Yes , i got the problem ArSen but what would change adding a name attribute to it , it will be same as targeting it with class no ? what i am asking is how can i target the exact value i want , think i am missing some logic while trying to fix the problem , i identified the problem correctly but fixing it is another part

Comment: I believe this is your culprit: `var beta = $('body .id_annonce').val();`. This will always return the value of the **first** element with that class. This command has no context of what was clicked.

Comment: @El_Vanja , yes i understood this is the problem i am trying to find another way of walking through it correctly with grabbing the exact value

Comment: @freedomn-m the 
console.log($('body .id_annonce').length)
VM863:1  the out put is 2

Comment: @RayanCh it's ok - I removed that as you added a comment that you're aware `$('body .id_annonce').val();` is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are grabbing the element by class (and multiple elements will have the same class) so you will not get a distinct one. You should therefore add a specific ID to the input and will be able to grab this then.

HTML output by PHP:

```php
echo '<input type="hidden"  value="' . $value["id"] . '" id="annonce-' . $value["id"] . '"  class="id_annonce">'
```

JS:

```js
var commander = $(this).val();
function goToAnnonce(id) {
  var beta = $('body #' + id).val();
  window.location.href = 'panier.php?id='+ commander +'?annonce='+ beta + ''; 
}
```

and to bind this to the button:

```php
echo '<button class="commander btn btn-md  btn-outline-dark " value="' . $value["id_commande"] . '" onclick="goToAnnonce(\'annonce-' . $value["id_commande"] . '\')"> Commander <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart  pr-2 "></i></button></div>';
```

**However** I'd like to point out that this is an overly complicated solution just to realize a button click that changes the page. This can be done A LOT simpler by either changing the button to a link:

```php
echo '<a href="panier.php?id=' . $value["id_commande"] . '&annonce=' . $value["id"] . 
'">Click me</a>';
```

Or by binding this click to the button. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link) if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Within the button click code, `this` refers to the button that's been clicked.  You can use that to navigate to the relevant hidden input.

My preferred method is to go *up* to a common parent (`$(this).closest(...`), then *down* to the input you want (`.find("input...`) This also works when you need multiple inputs, up once, down multiple times.  It also reduces the rigidity that comes with .next() and similar.

In your case:

```js
$(".commander").on("click", function() {
  var commander = $(this).val();
  var beta = $(this).closest(".card-body").find(".id_annonce").val();
  console.log('panier.php?id=' + commander + '?annonce=' + beta + '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-body">
  <input type="hidden" value="123" class="id_annonce">
  <button type="button" class="commander">Commander</button>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  <input type="hidden" value="456" class="id_annonce">
  <button type="button" class="commander">Commander</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've misunderstood the problem before. You can try this-

```
$('.commander').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const commander = $(this).val();
    const beta = $(this).siblings('.id_annonce').val();

    window.location.href = 'panier.php?id='+ commander +'?annonce='+ beta + ''; 
});
```

The `id_annonce` input field is a sibling of the `commander` button. So you can grab this by getting the clicked commander's sibling id_annonce.

Comment: I just tested , this end still grabbing the old value instead of grabbing $value["id"] == 19 it grabs 18 which is the previous one , the problem is because i am focusing the same " class name" and i think it's because of html dom but i really have no idea how i could fix it or what kind of trick i should do

Comment: This will not generate any different output from the code in the question.

Comment: Does the redirect happen on any event listener? Say clicking on any button.

Comment: php is executed on the server, jquery is executed on the client - of course it's after :)   The question is: when is your provided (in the question) jquery code run - is it on a button click?  Which button?

Comment: @freedomn-m both of the buttons , the only button who is working is details which redirect to another page , the other one it grab me the previous value not the exact one so it works only with the first result of the row.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I've updated the code. Have a try if it works. Thanks @freedomn-m for the idea.